# How can an istream evaluate to false?

Tags: c++

In the below code, we call `in.get(c)` repeatedly and it returns an `isteam&` each time. How does an instance of `isteam&` evaluate to false in the while statement?

I checked that `in.get` isn't returning a null reference so I'm not sure how else it could evaluate to false.

```
istream &to_std_out(istream &in) {
    char c;
    while (in.get(c)) {
        cout << c;
    }
    in.clear();
    return in;
}

int main() {
    istringstream str("A sailor went to see, see, see.");
    to_std_out(str);
}
```

Comment: Here's a detailed explanation: [std::istream::operator!()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!)

Answer (score 1):

The streams have a conversion operator to `void*` or an `explicit` conversion operator to `bool`. The stream converts to `false` if at least one of the state bits `std::ios_base::badbit` or `std:: ios_base::failbit` is set.